# Nuxt 3 i18n: TypeError: _ctx.localPath is not a function

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm on Nuxt 3 with the Nuxt i18n module
I just want to make a simple routing system with locales.

So i have read the doc and make this on my Nuxt 3 pages :

```
    <script setup>
        import { useLocalePath, useSwitchLocalePath, useLocaleHead, useBrowserLocale } from '#i18n'

        const { locale } = useI18n()

        const localePath = useLocalePath()

    </script>
```

but when I call localePath in my vue methods, nuxt shows this error : TypeError: _ctx.localPath is not a function

The code :

```
    methods:{
        exampleMethod(){
            this.$router.push(this.localePath("/studio"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error by writing this :

```js
this.$router.push("/"+useI18n().locale.value+"/studio")
```